# Routing rule condition using query parameter not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to redirect only when there is `?img.crop=` piece in query parameter. E.g. I have this link: "http://somedomain.com/pic.jpg?img.crop=400x400". I want to crop image only when there is `?img.crop=` piece.
I've tried to use `<KeyPrefixEquals>?img.crop=</KeyPrefixEquals>` , but it's not working --> only original image loads up and doesn't redirect, even when `?img.crop=` piece provided in URL.

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
          <KeyPrefixEquals>?img.crop=</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <Protocol>https</Protocol>
      <HostName>~*hidden*~</HostName>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>default/resizeLambdaFunction?params=</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
      <HttpRedirectCode>307</HttpRedirectCode>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routing rules don't support evaluating query parameters.

`<KeyPrefixEquals>` evaluates only the object key prefix, which includes only the object key name and excludes any query string.  Additionally, it's a "prefix" match, so it is left-anchored by definition.

`<ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>` does allow you to inject query string elements ahead of the object key during the rewrite, but there is no built-in support for the matching you're attempting.

Comment: I've seen some blog posts, where author says that it is possible, but mostly people say that it's impossible. So most probably those, who says that it's possible doesn't fully understand the problem.
Thank you!

Comment: Many things *are* possible with S3 redirect rules, but matching against the query string is not possible, and matching against a suffix or mid-string value within the object key is not possible.